# Matrix of structs in C

Tags: c, matrix, struct

How do I make a matrix of structs or a matrix of pointers to structs? The elements in the matrix `a` should be structs of type `Area`.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
  char type_toy[20];
  int nr;
  char town[20];
  char direction;
} Area;

void AllocMatrix(int N, int M, Area** a) {
  int i;
  a = malloc(N * sizeof(Area *));
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    a[i] = calloc(M, sizeof(Area*));
  }
}

int main() {
  int N, M;
  Area** a;
  printf("N = ..., M = ...");
  scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);
  AllocMatrix(N, M, a);

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
      scanf ("%s", &a[i][j].town);
      scanf ("%s", &a[i][j].type_toy);
      scanf ("%d", &a[i][j].nr);
      scanf ("%s", &a[i][j].direction);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need `a[i] = calloc(M, sizeof(Area)); ` as you are allocating memory for `M` matrices in the `i`-th row

Comment: Very often, in C, it is worthwhile to represent matrices as one-dimensional arrays (perhaps as a final *flexible array member* of some `struct`) and access them with e.g. a macro `#define matrix_at(m,i,j) m[(i)*width+(j)]`

Answer (score 3):

> void AllocMatrix(int N, int M, Area** a) {

should be `Area***` because otherwise the pass-by-value copy of the pointer will hold the address of the  allocated memory, and the caller function would not be able to obtain it.

Further,

> a[i] = calloc(M, sizeof(Area*));

should be `sizeof(Area)`, and if my first point applies, it should be `(*a)[i] =`

Comment: I also have some warning when compiling: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, buet argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]
scanf ("%s", &a[i][j].town);
^

Comment: @VladŞtefanDieaconu remove the `&`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple option, if you don't require to have the function:

```
scanf("%d %d", &N, &M); 

Area (*a)[M] = calloc( N, sizeof *a );
```

and the rest of your code the same.  It'd be good to check `M > 0` before doing `malloc`, and also check that `malloc` does not return `NULL` before proceeding,

---

Also your scanfs are incorrect:

- The `"%s"` should be `"%19s"` to prevent a buffer overflow
- The `&` should not be included for `%s`, this is because `%s` expects a pointer to the first character to write (not a pointer to the whole array), and when you use the name of an array, it is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element already.
- `char direction;` should have `"%c"`